# My function should not accept arguments of type other than that specified

Tags: python-3.x

My function is still accepting other data type value as argument. But I want my function to take only string as argument.

It should raise a `TypeError` if it is given something other than a string.

I'm using python 3.9.5 version.

```
def fun(string:str):

    return string
```

Output:

```
>>> fun(123)
123
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, python ignores these types of annotation. Only specific modules and programs like inspect, mypy etc.,can understand these types of annotations. (I'm not sure abt these modules. But it is modules specific)

You can add one more line so that if anything other than string is given as argument you'll get assertion error.

```
def fun(string:str):
    assert isinstance(string, str)
    return string

print(fun('425')) # output: 425
print(fun(425)) # output : assertion error
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to know what is the problem in my code why it is accepting other than string as argument. Cause I had specific argument data type.

Comment: By default, python ignores these types of annotation. Only specific modules and programs like inspect, mypy etc.,can understand these types of annotations. (I'm not sure abt these modules. But it is modules specific)

Comment: I've added my above comment in my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def fun(string: str):
    assert isinstance(string, str), "TypeError"
    return string
```